# Spring Security 3.1 Authentication ProviderManager throwing NotSerializableException

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, spring-security

I  am building a JSF2 web app with Spring Security 3.1 for security things.
Everytime when restarting tomcat, I am getting a NotSerializableException thrown by ProviderManager of Spring Security but the webapp is working perfectly. I am afraid that will causes maybe some problems when deploying to production.
Does anyone know how to make the ProviderManager Serializable
Here is the exception:

```
SEVERE: IOException while loading persisted sessions: java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1355)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObject(StandardSession.java:1619)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObjectData(StandardSession.java:1084)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doLoad(StandardManager.java:282)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.load(StandardManager.java:202)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.startInternal(StandardManager.java:489)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5537)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:4033)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:425)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1345)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1546)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1556)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1556)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1524)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObject(StandardSession.java:1695)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObjectData(StandardSession.java:1101)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doUnload(StandardManager.java:430)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.unload(StandardManager.java:351)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stopInternal(StandardManager.java:516)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5719)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:4026)
... 7 more
```

Comment: Why are you trying to save a service bean in the session? This is a design problem and should be fixed by not saving a reference to it, not trying to hack serialization onto something that isn't semantically serializable.

Comment: I am not saving it in a session but maybe it's JSF `@SessionScoped` which is trying to save it. Have you an idea on how preventing that?

Comment: Is this a new application?

Comment: If it is a new application, what I have to do?

Comment: If it were a new application, I'd say "just don't use JSF, because it's full of this sort of problem". Not sure exactly how to go about troubleshooting this.

Comment: It's too late now, I will try to implement a custom authenitcation provider and test it, anyway thanks @chrylis

Comment: A custom authentication provider is the wrong approach. You have to find out why the provider is being added to the session in the first place and fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your LoginBean, simply replace the `@SessionScoped` by `@RequestScoped` because ther is no need to save the entered user informations while logging in  in a session variable, you can access them with the Spring Security features like this

```
org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User user = (org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
String name = user.getUsername();
```